# Registering Slash Commands from cog nextcord

Tags: python, slash, nextcord

So I'm trying to register a slash command in cogs with nextcord (python)
It says it has loaded it with `bot.load_extension(blahblah(bot)` but it doesn't register, not even in the DMS, here is the code

```
from nextcord.ext  import commands
class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot=bot
    guilds = IDOFSERVER
    @nextcord.slash_command(name="slashincog",guild_ids=[guilds])
    async def slashincog(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Testing")

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Is there anything I have to do to load a slash command? I've tried many tutorials, but none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some advice from the Nextcord Discord server. #3 might be the issue here, but in case you haven't solved it, you can look through the other possibilities.

**Most common issues**

1. You didn't invite the bot to your guild with the application.commands oauth enabled. Go to the developer portal, make an invite with both bot and applications.commands enabled, and re-authorize your bot for your server.
2. You're using global commands and probably haven't waited (up to) an hour for them to appear.
3. You're adding the cogs with slash commands in them too late inside of your bot. You either need to add them before on_connect is called (preferably before the bot is even started), or run the global and/or guild sync methods manually.

**Lesser common issues**

4. Discord gets weird sometimes and doesn't refresh available commands. Try restarting your Discord client.
5. You're overriding on_connect, which adds the application commands to bot/client (including ones inside cogs) and rolls out global commands. Either stop overriding it, or add `bot.add_all_application_commands()` and `await bot.sync_application_commands()` to it.
6. You're overriding on_guild_available, which rolls out commands to guilds. Either stop overriding it, or add the following codeblock to it:

```py
try:
    await bot.sync_application_commands(guild_id=guild.id)
except Forbidden:
    pass
```